# Fundamental Theorem of Calculus Part 1 question

Tags: integration, derivatives

us FTC part 1 to solve this question:

$$g(x)=\int_{1}^{e^x} 6\ln(t)\ dt$$

find the derivative of g(x).

The answer is: $$6 + 6e^x(x-1)$$

can anyone tell me why this is the answer and how do you get it?

Comment: Are you sure you have the right question? Because $6+6e^x(x-1)$ is not the derivative, it is $g(x)$ itself.

Comment: By enforcing the substitution $t=e^{u}$ we get

$$ g(x)=\int_{1}^{e^x}6\log(t)\,dt = \int_{0}^{x}6u e^{u}\,du $$
hence by the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus $\frac{d}{dx}g(x) = \color{red}{6x\,e^x}$.

Answer (score 3):

Hint: set
$$
h(y)=\int_1^y6\ln t\,dt,
$$
then $g(x)=h(e^x)$. Apply the chain rule and FTC.

Answer (score 0):

Let $G$ be 
$$G(x)=\int_{a(x)}^{b(x)}f(t,x)dt$$

so it has as a derivative

$$G'(x)=f(b(x),x) \cdot b'(x)-f(a(x),x) \cdot a'(x)+\int_{a(x)}^{b(x)}\frac{\partial f(t,x)}{\partial x}dt$$
then in your case 
$$G(x)=\int_{1}^{e^x} 6\ln(t)\ dt$$ so

$$G'(x)=6\log(e^x) \cdot e^x-6\log(1) \cdot 0+\int_{1}^{e^x}0 \cdot dx$$
$$G'(x)=6\cdot xe^x$$

Comment: Note that $f(t,x)=6\ln(t)$. Therefore, $\frac{\partial}{\partial x}f(t,x)=?$

Comment: See [Leibniz Rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule).

Comment: sorry i have fixed it; $\frac{\partial}{\partial x}f(t,x)=0$ thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Just doing a simple integral:

$$6\int_1^{e^x}\ln(t)\ dt=6\big[t(\ln(t)-1)\big]_1^{e^x}=6(e^x(\ln(e^x)-1)+6=6e^x(x-1)+6$$

The derivative with respect to $x$ is

$$6e^x(x-1)+6e^x=6xe^x.$$

---

By the fundamental theorem

$$\frac{d}{dx}6\int_1^{e^x}\ln(t)\ dt=6(\ln(e^x)e^x-\ln(1))=6xe^x.$$